# Typescript - ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

In my console I keep getting `ReferenceError: exports is not defined` as an error.

Code:

app.ts:

```
import {IDetails} from "./interfaces/IDetails";

class MyClass implements IDetails{
    constructor(){}

    public render (elem: string, text: string) {
        let el: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(elem);
        el.textContent = text;
        el.innerText = text;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    let myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.render('body', 'Hello World!');
};
```

IDetails.ts:

```
export interface IDetails {
    elem: string,
    text: string
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: I have edited my question with `webpack.config.js` and `tsconfig.json`. It might also be worthy to notice that I'm viewing the files directly from Webstorm in my Chrome browser. Could that be an issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this in Node.js?

Comment: I'm viewing from Webstorm directly. Please check my edits.

Comment: I have had the same problem and tried to fix it for couple of minutes with no effect and the problem was that I had my output file in root directory but webpack was creating file in dist/ directory I was using the old one in root directory. :facepalm:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "allowJs": false

Or to exclude the webpack config file from the typescript compiler using exclude https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Why would excluding the webpack.config.js help? Thanks.

Comment: because your error seems to be related to module.exports function in your webpack file

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to your Typescript config options if you're exporting CommonJS modules. You can fix this by running your bundle through a command line utility called Browserify. See http://thejsguy.com/javascript/browserify/2015/01/05/browserify-getting-started.html

Comment: I have edited my question with tsconfig.json and webpack.config.js